# jQuery UI Datepicker mousewheel support

Tags: jquery-ui, mousewheel, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there a addon somewhere that adds mousewheel support to the jQuery UI datepicker?  (So that using the mousewheel over the calendar causes the month to advance/go back.)

The [changelog](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Changelog/1.7#Datepicker) seems to indicate that mousewheel support was added in 1.7, but it [looks like that changeset](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/detail?spec=svn2598&r=525) actually had nothing to do with the datepicker.  A cursory search of 1.8 indicates there's no built-in mousewheel support.

I know [Keith Wood's datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) supports the mousewheel, but I'm using [this timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), which depends on jQuery UI's datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily added by adding the following code to your ready function. It uses the [jQuery mousewheel extension](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos) and adds a live event listener for mousewheel events on jQuery UI datepicker divs. If one is detected, it triggers the `click` event on the prev/next month button.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PSFgY/

```
$('.ui-datepicker').live("mousewheel", function(event, delta){
    if(delta < 0){
        $(this).find('.ui-datepicker-next').click();
    } else {
        $(this).find('.ui-datepicker-prev').click();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed; thanks!  I did change the class to `.ui-datepicker-group` (and added `$(this).parent().find`...) so that the wheel wouldn't kick in when over the timepicker portion of the dropdown.

Comment: I think `delta` is now `event.wheelDelta`

Answer (score 2):

**A small update:**
As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.
Also I had to use `event.originalEvent.wheelDelta` to get the delta.

```
$(document).on('mousewheel', '.ui-datepicker', function (event) {
    var sel = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 ? '.ui-datepicker-next' : '.ui-datepicker-prev';
    $(this).find(sel).click();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: If you're using [brandonaaron's mousewheel plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) you can use `event.deltaY` instead, which might be more cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to handle the problem especially when minimum and maximum dates are set:

```
$('.ui-datepicker').bind("mousewheel", function(e){
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if(delta <  0){
        $(this).find('.ui-datepicker-next').click();
    } else {
        $(this).find('.ui-datepicker-prev').click();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```